# Javascript match

Tags: javascript, match

Suppose this is my code

```
var str="abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;"; 

var patt1=/abc=([\d]+)/g;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

i want the output as 1234587,19855284

this doesnt return the number but instead returns the complete string which is in the pattern
if i remove 'g' from the pattern it returns abcd=1234578,1234578 what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you want

> 1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284,1234587,19855284

then try this

```
var str="abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;";

var patt1=/([\d]+)/g;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

or you can use the array index as sjngm mentioned

Answer (score 2):

`match()` returns an array. The first entry (index 0) is always the matching string. Following that you get the matching group(s).

The `toString()`-logic of an array takes all elements and joins them with ", ". You can use e.g. `join("-")` to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
var str = "abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;abc=1234587;abc=19855284;";
        str = str.replace(/abc=/gi, '');
        document.write(str);
```